# parsec error in haskelwiki tutorial

Tags: haskell

I was following the code in http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hitchhikers_guide_to_Haskell, and the code (in chapter 2) gives an error. There is no author name/email mentioned with the tutorial, so I am coming here for advise. The code is below, and the error occurs on the "eof" word.

```
module Main where

import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

parseInput = 
  do dirs <- many dirAndSize
     eof
     return dirs

data Dir = Dir Int String deriving Show

dirAndSize = 
  do size <- many1 digit
     spaces
     dir_name <- anyChar `manyTill` newline
     return (Dir (read size) dir_name)

main = do
    input <- getContents
    putStrLn ("Debug: got inputs: " ++ input)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial was written a long time ago, when parsec was simple. Nowadays, since parsec-3, the library can wrap monads, so you now have to specify (or otherwise disambiguate) the type to use at some points. This is one of them, giving `eof` e.g. the expression type signature `eof :: Parser ()` makes it compile.

Comment: Thanks. Also, calling parseInput from Main sets the context. In the above example, the code was being built, and the Main code was from the previous version and not calling parseInput. When I revised the Main code segment from the next section, it worked.